# How to get rid of Copy trait when MaybeUninit is used?

Tags: rust

This is the code:

```
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

struct Foo<V> {
    a : [V; 10]
}

impl<V: Copy> Foo<V> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        unsafe {
            Self {
                a: *MaybeUninit::<[V; 10]>::uninit().assume_init_mut(),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile if I remove `Copy` trait from `V`. How can I get rid of such a requirement?

Comment: This code is terribly unsound, and immediate UB for almost all types.

Comment: This code works just fine in this crate of mine: https://github.com/yegor256/micromap No errors, many unit tests, no UB. What exactly is "unsound"? Just the presence of the work `unsafe` makes you think it's unsound?

Comment: Well you use it in the only case where it's not UB: when `V` is `MaybeUninit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with your code is not `Copy`, it's that your code is likely<sup>1</sup> unsound.

It is unsound (Undefined Behavior) in Rust to produce a value with [an uninitialized bit pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initialization-invariant) *even* if a bit pattern is valid for the value<sup>2</sup>. Exceptions to this rule are:

- `MaybeUninit`, specifically designed for uninitialized memory.
- Zero Sized-Types, such as `()`, since they take zero space, and thus have zero bits.

If you do not wish to initialize the Vs in `Foo::a` to valid values, this leaves a single solution: altering `Foo`.

The easiest solution is to use something like [`ArrayVec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.7.2/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html) to handle all the `unsafe` code for you:

```
struct Foo<V> { a: ArrayVec<V, 10> }
```

Unlike a `Vec`, `ArrayVec` stores the elements in an array (hence the name). Unlike an array, the number of elements in `ArrayVec` is dynamic (between 0 and N).

There's a slight overhead to using `ArrayVec`: the length is tracking with one `usize`. There may be slimmer alternatives on crates.io.

If you prefer to do it yourself -- whether for educational purposes, or because that one `usize` is actually an impediment -- then you can take a leaf from `ArrayVec`'s book and switch `Foo` to:

```
struct Foo<V> { a: [MaybeUninit<V>; 10] }
```

It will requires some other part of the code tracking the number of elements actually set, and using `unsafe` to access them. And it will be unsound if you get it wrong... but it'll be sound if you do get it right.

For such a `Foo`, using nightly and `#![feature(maybe_uninit_uninit_array)]`, the initialization is:

```
impl<V> Foo<V> {
    fn new() -> Self { Self { a: MaybeUninit::uninit_array() } }
}
```

If nightly is undesirable, then you can take a leaf from [element by element initialization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element):

```
impl<V> Foo<V> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        //  Safety:
        //  - `[MaybeUninit<_>; _]` can be left uninitialized soundly.
        let a = unsafe {
            MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<V>, 10]>::uninit().assume_init()
        };

        Self { a }
    }
}
```

This is sound because the `T` is `[MaybeUninit<V>; 10]`, which can indeed have an uninitialized value.

<sup>1</sup> *Without seeing the actual usage, it's not definitive, but the structure of the presented code is such that in most circumstances it will be unsound.*

<sup>2</sup> *For an `i32` all bit patterns are valid, for a `bool` only 2 patterns are valid.*

Comment: In the non-nightly example, you're missing an `unsafe` block around `MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init()`. Also just to be on the safe side, I'd recommend using `MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<_>; 10]>::uninit().assume_init()`, just to be sure that, if you end up changing the definition of `a` to a non-array, you get a compile-time error instead of silent UB.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues: Both good points. I also added a safety comment explain why the manipulation is indeed sound.

Comment: Try to tell all this to the creators or `std::Vec`. Ask them to get rid of all the `unsafe` code inside the vector and see what they tell you :)

Comment: @yegor256: I've written low-level collections, so I've used `unsafe` fairly extensively. It _is_ a sharp tool, though, so it should be used cautiously, and even though I am fairly comfortable with it, I'll still favor solutions that do not require it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. my very immature observation so far is the following: if you aim for high performance, you have to deal with pointers and direct memory access in Rust. Vectors, Boxes, etc. are simply too slow in corner cases. They are perfect for general purpose programming though. Again, check my lib where I'm using the code mentioned above: https://github.com/yegor256/micromap

Comment: @yegor256: Ah, memory allocations... I've been rekindling my work on a `Storage` proposal for Rust of late, trying to make it RFC-worthy. If possible, I'd like for the regular collections to be usable with inline storage -- to avoid duplicating all the logic, again and again. You can see the state of my current efforts at https://github.com/matthieu-m/storage. Fair warning the "collection" folder is more concerned with providing a demo of the flexibility of the solution, rather than production-ready collections, so it's intentionally sparse, and not too well-tested.

Answer (score 1):

The code @Stargateur [previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76086468/1), (it's since been removed from their answer so I'm quoting it here):

> ```rust
> use std::mem::MaybeUninit;
>
> struct Foo<V> {
>     a: [V; 10],
> }
>
> impl<V> Foo<V> {
>     pub fn new() -> Self {
>         unsafe {
>             Self {
>                 a: MaybeUninit::<[V; 10]>::uninit().assume_init(),
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

which fixes the immediate issue of getting rid of the `Copy` constraint on `V`, has a serious flaw, it's *unsound* as it can be used to cause [undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) [behavior](https://predr.ag/blog/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-undefined-behavior/) in safe Rust:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = Foo::<Vec<u8>>::new();
}
```

To fix that flaw you *have to* mark `Foo::new` as `unsafe` and should specify the preconditions a caller has to uphold in it's documentation:

```rust
impl<V> Foo<V> {
    /// ##### Safety
    /// This function is unsafe because the caller has to guarantee that
    /// the type `V` does not need initialization, that's true for example
    /// for `MaybeUninit<T>` or ZSTs.
    pub unsafe fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: MaybeUninit::<[V; 10]>::uninit().assume_init(),
        }
    }
}
```

Of course to use it you also have to guarantee the necessary constraints.

Comment: Or else I can just embed a mechanism inside `Foo` that would manage the content of the unitialized memory and only allow reading the parts that are initialized. This is exactly how my crate works: https://github.com/yegor256/micromap Honestly, I can't understand why you guys are so triggered by the `unsafe` keyword. The entire `std` library is based on its intensive usage.

Comment: Creating a value of type `V` which needs to be initialized is UB, not just reading it.

Comment: in your example above I only see the problem of reading, where you do `x.a[0]`. How would another UB look, which you just mentioned ("creating a value `V`")?

Comment: the first line in `main` is already UB.

Comment: Can you turn the mantra "It's UB" into a practical error situation? :) Again, keep in mind that `a` is private inside `Foo` and we can easily forbid dangerous usage scenarios.

Comment: Read the link on [misconseptions around UB](https://predr.ag/blog/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-undefined-behavior/) please. If you care for your code even a little tiny bit you don't include UB in it imo.

Comment: Some code in Rust may not be written without `unsafe`. There are two layers of Rust programming, AFAIU: 1) system level, where `std::Vec` is staying, 2) user level, where we use `vec![]`. Of course, at the second level we must avoid `unsafe`, but at the first level it's _impossible_ to avoid it.

Comment: @yegor256 it's not about using unsafe it's about invoke UB, if you invoke UB your program can bug at any time, the practical impact is first no one will use your library, the second impact is rocket that are crashing. Rust say you **can't** have uninitiated variable even if you don't use it, unless they exist in union that what MaybeUninit is for. it's a union that allow uninitiated variable. https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/mem/maybe_uninit.rs.html#249, the solution of matthieu will not cost any perf impact, you need to keep the array in a MaybeUninit state since you handle the len manually